# is it possible to disable-output-escaping twice in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have XML that has encoded HTML data. I am trying to render the data but can't seem to figure out how. Best I can tell is I need to `disable-output-escaping="yes"` twice but not sure how to do that.

For example, this is a snippet of my XML:

```
<root>
    <node value="&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;body&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;" />
</root>
```

My XSLT is outputting HTML. Here is the rendered output (the HTML source) with various options

- `<xsl:value-of select="@value" />` outputs `&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;hi&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;`
- `<xsl:value-of select="@value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` outputs `&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;`

I would like it to output `<b>hi</b>` to the HTML source so its actually rendered as a bolded hi. Does that make sense? Is that possible?

Comment: Inform yourself about xslt 3 function parse-xml or saxon parse if possible. We dont know your environment.

Comment: It seems to be that your second approach should work as long as your XSLT processor and your use case support `disable-output-escaping`. http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuU uses that approach and outputs `<b>hi</b>`. So unless you use a Mozilla browser or some other XSLT processor not supporting `disable-output-escaping` I would expect you to get the desired result.

Comment: @uL1 This is XSLT 1.0. I'm trying to do this in SharePoint.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I made a mistake in the XML I have. I updated it. If you see now, you'll see where the issue is. http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuU/1

Comment: Does Sharepoint allow you to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e(v=vs.110).aspx to call into .NET code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sharepoint as a Microsoft .NET product uses XslCompiledTransform you could try to implement the unescaping and parsing with extension "script" (C# or VB or JScript.NET code embedded in XSLT) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl mf">


  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="mf">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>
    public string Unescape(string input)
    {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocumentFragment frag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
    frag.InnerXml = input;
    return frag.InnerText;
    }

    public XPathNavigator ParseXml(string xmlInput)
    {
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlInput))
    {
    return new XPathDocument(sr).CreateNavigator();
    }
    }
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <div>
      <xsl:copy-of select="mf:ParseXml(mf:Unescape(@value))" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have access to an XSLT processor (like any version of Saxon 9.7 or Exselt or the latest Altova or XmlPrime) supporting the XPath 3 functions `parse-xml` and `parse-xml-fragment` you can write that template without extension functions (in a `version="3.0"` stylesheet) as

```
<xsl:template match="node">
    <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml(string(parse-xml-fragment(@value)))"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping is the process of turning `<` into `&lt;`. If you disable escaping, it will leave `<` as `<`. What you want to achieve is to turn `&lt;` into `<`, which would normally be called "unescaping".

In the normal course of events, a parser performs unescaping, while a serializer performs escaping. So if you want to unescape characters, you need to put them through a parsing process, which means you need to take the content of the `@value` attribute and put it through an operation like fn:parse-xml-fragment() in XPath 3.0, or an equivalent extension function in your chosen processor.

Answer (score 0):

Output your result with `disable-output-escaping`, then treat it again in another XSL with `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: How would I treat it in another XSL?