# how to apply templates to an escaped xml string

Tags: xslt

I'm working with a CMS running on ASP that has text fields for data input. It passes that data to XSLT 1.0 render templates in the form of `<fieldname>escaped field val</fieldname>` All characters are escaped to their HTML equivalents so if I enter an xml string in to the CMS of

```
<test><foo><bar>bar val</bar></foo><something>something val</something></test>
```

The render templates get a value of

```
&lt;test&gt;&lt;foo&gt;&lt;bar&gt;bar val&lt;/bar&gt;&lt;/foo&gt;&lt;something&gt;something val&lt;/something&gt;&lt;/test&gt;
```

Is it possible to turn that escaped xml string into actual xml I can apply a template to?

Here's a template with some stuff I've tried so far. I'm able to run C# in the templates so I tried various combos of disable-output-escaping and my own manual C# methods, but no matter what, when I pass it to node-set, it doesn't become something I can apply a template to.

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    public string makeTags(string input)
    {
        return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
    }
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/data">

    <h1>working</h1>

    <xsl:variable name="outputHTMLText">
        <xsl:value-of select="user:makeTags(output)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="outputNodes" select="exslt:node-set($outputHTMLText)" />


        <xsl:copy-of select="$outputNodes"  />


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` works only when the result tree is serialized, i.e. written out to the output file. Instead of using a variable, write an intermediate result to a file, then process that file with your "real" XSL.

Comment: Unfortunately with this CMS I can only specify one render template per set of data fields. I considered a way to sort of do what you're describing which is to have the render template contain C# that uses an XslCompiledTransform object in a sort of shell xslt that contains the custom display xslt in an xsl:Text, But I feel like having the server parse xslts while it parses xslts would be horrible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Within .NET and `XslCompiledTransform` you can use

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    public XPathNavigator parse(string input)
    {
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
        {
          return new XPathDocument(sr).CreateNavigator();
        }
    }
</msxsl:script>
```

to parse an XML string into a XPathNavigator then represented as node-set (of a single node) in XSLT to apply templates to e.g.

`<xsl:apply-templates select="user:parse(Output)/test"/>`

This assumes the escaping you have shown is only the effect of the xml or html output method when you try to output the value you have.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948619/252228.